# PHP RegExp for PDF Metadata

Tags: php, regex

I'm stuck with a piece of RegExp to retrieve the page count of a PDF within the Metadata tag embed on the PDF.

The metadata looks like this: `<</Metadata 1 0 R/Pages 5 0 R/Type/Catalog>>`

I need the first number after `<</Metadata` which, in this case is `1` but, it could be 100 according to the page count.

I've tried matching the string in between with `(?=metadata).*(?=r\/pages)` but, if fails in some PDF formats due the end (`pages`) string.

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried matching the string in between with (?=metadata).*(?=r\/pages) but, if fails in some PDF formats due the end (pages) string. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not forget to share what you have tried when posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches too much text starting with `metadata` up to but not including `r/pages`, as you have a positive look-ahead at the beginning and end.

You need to make use of `\d` shorthand character class that matches a digit (or its equivalent `[0-9]` character class). To match the first integer number after `<<\/Metadata` you may use a look-behind, or use a capturing group for the digit pattern:

```
(?<=<<\/Metadata\s)\d+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jY7bW0/1). Or use [this one](https://regex101.com/r/jY7bW0/2) with a capturing group (it is preferable if the number of whitespace symbols may be more than one):

```
<<\/Metadata\s+(\d+)
```